# Is $ac \equiv bc\:(mod\: n) \iff a \equiv b\:(mod\: n)$ valid?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Is it is true that:

$$ac \equiv bc \:(mod\:n) \iff a \equiv b \:(mod\:n)$$

Or is the rule instead that:

$$ac \equiv bc \:(mod\:n) \implies a \equiv b\:(mod\:n)$$

Or that:

$$a \equiv b\:(mod\:n) \implies ac \equiv bc \:(mod\:n)$$

Comment: if $n$ is a prime, both directions hold

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$2 \times 4 \equiv 4 \times 4$ mod $8$ But $2 \not \equiv 4$ mod $8$. The second rule holds!

Comment: Ah, there's the counterexample I needed. Thank you!

Comment: I can add that the cancellation for multiplication ONLY holds when there are NO zero-divisors or even none of multiplicants are zero divors, in the example given here, 2 and 4 are zero divisors for modulo 8 so it doesn't hold then.

Answer (score 1):

The third rule also holds since, for some $t,c\in \mathbb{Z}$: $$a \equiv b \pmod{n} \iff a=b+nt \implies ac=bc+n(ct) \implies ac \equiv bc \pmod{n}.$$

If $c \ne 0$, then the above holds in both directions.